# Замена текста на картинку

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Мне надо сделать так что когда получаю ответ из БД mysql в виде одной цифры,то каким то образом он менял путь к картинке (например через JS скрипт)

Например я получил ответ из БД в виде числа 25 и должна показатся картинка у которой название 25.png

Надеюсь на помощь,заранее спасибо!

Comment: а в чём проблема? получаете ответ из БД 25 записываете в переменную и рендерите html, где эту переменную подставляете <img src="путь до картинки + название переменной + .png">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам скорее нужна канкатенация:

```
<?php
   $image_id = 25; //Тут вы получаете свою цифру
   $image = $image_id.".png";
```

Теперь в переменной `$image` у вас будет `25.png` .

Для `html` это будет что-то вроде:

```
<img src="<?=$image_id?>.png">
```